# visualforce page does not exist

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to create some visualforce pages. But I can watch result. In each page which I create I see text: Page does not exist. Is is very simple page with one "h1" tag. And when I press buttob "preview" I get string: "Page testPage does not exist". Anybody knows Why I can preview my pages?

Comment: Weird. You are able to click Save / QuickSave, correct? You need to do it before preview runs. Are yous sure your session didn't time out for example? How do you create the pages (in Setup? Developer Console? In API tool such as Eclipse IDE / MavensMate / etc?) Can you maybe include some screenshots?

Comment: Thanks. I dont wknow why but now I can watch my pages. I didn't do nothing for this. I think problems was with plugin (IlluminatedCloud) which I use in IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new VF page from setup in salesforce, it creates a placeholder which you can edit but until you save that page it will not be available for you to view. So please go ahead and click 'save' or 'quick save' or use 'Ctrl+s'.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG6M1.jpg)

After that the preview button will work.

Have a great day!